# Radio Buttons in HTML And JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am just wondering if anyone can help me insert radio buttons into my HTML webpage to insert the difficulty of the exam, This is my question
5. Add a set of radio buttons to the form to accept a level of entry such as GCSE, AS or A2. Write a function that displays the level of entry to the user in an alert box so that the level can be confirmed or rejected.

Here is my code, Can anyone help me out please

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Entry</title>

<script language="javascript"" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
            var result = true;
            var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your Exam ID Number \n";
            document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('Exam Number').style.color="red";
            result = false;
}

if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
            }


}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
            font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
  <table width="50%" border="0">
            <tr>
                            <td id="name">Name</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
            </tr>                <tr>
                            <td id="Exam Number">Exam ID Number</td>
                            <td><input type="Number" name="ID Number"maxlength="4" ></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                            <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
            </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

JFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jgv9q/

Comment: well isn't that your home work or something..? -__-

Comment: Have you even tried doing a google search on how to make radio buttons in HTML? That would be a great place to start.

Comment: maybe a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512615/how-to-make-it-so-my-radio-buttons-is-html-javascript-only-makes-the-radio-butto?rq=1

Comment: w3schools probably has an example or two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the radio buttons in your html and run code to find out which one was checked. You should be referencing w3Schools when just learning but got you started here.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyysy/1/

```
 <tr>
                <td>Exam Level</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="exam" value="GCSE">GCSE<br>
<input type="radio" name="exam" value="AS">AS<br>
<input type="radio" name="exam" value="ALevel">ALevel</td>
            </tr>
```

and then to find out which is checked, you can use:

```
 var x = document.getElementsByName('exam')
        for(var k=0;k<x.length;k++)
          if(x[k].checked){
            alert('Option selected: ' + x[k].value)
          }
```

Read more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: avoid referencing w3schools, they're not a reliable source, here is why: [http://www.w3fools.com/](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: ...but its a great place to start for a GCSE or A-Level student making a website, I wouldn't advise them to reference against the actual w3c.

Would you recommend another website that is simple to use for beginners to reference HTML tags?

Comment: I personally have learned everything I know by simply searching, never actually stick to anyone specifically, but I learned a LOT from Stack Overflow... I just had a quick look, and found the following website providing a couple of examples (also discouraging to use w3schools by the way): [http://www.skilledup.com/learn/programming/free-beginner-html-tutorials/](http://www.skilledup.com/learn/programming/free-beginner-html-tutorials/)